# Python - Serial Communication with Raw Byte Transfer

Tags: python, pyserial, uart

I'm trying to setup a custom Python GUI to interface with an MCU.
A simple UART protocoll shall be used for communication where 8 Bytes per Message are used.
The first 4 bytes are the message id, the last 4 bytes are the message content.

The protocoll is implemented on the mcu and the communication works fine with hterm.
However I've some odd problem with the Serial lib in Python.
Here is a simple example:

```
COM_Port = "COM5"
Baudrate = 19200
SerialPort = serial.Serial(COM_Port,Baudrate,bytesize=8,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=1,timeout=None)
while True:
    bytestream = SerialPort.read(8)#read 8 bytes
    stream = str(bytestream).strip('b')#remove
    print(stream) # just print data
    #queue_in.put(bytestream)# later on data shell be processed outside
```

If i now send the MSG: {10,1,0,0,0,50,0,0}
Hterm shows: {10,1,0,0,0,50,0,0} - which is correct
Python terminal shows a string: '\n\x01\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00' - not correct
(The first byte is \n which is 10 okay)
The fifth byte is very strange with 0x002?

However if is send the MSG: {255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255}
Hterm shows: {255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255} - which is correct
Python terminal shows a string: '\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff' - which is correct

My guess is that this issue is related to the read() function which does some internal conversion?
Has somebody seen this behaviour before or can give me a clue of what is going on here?

Comment: `\x002` is actually a `\x00` and then a character `2` which has the ASCII hex code `50`, so everything is correct. The string representation of `bytes` shows values associated with printable ASCII characters as such (which isn't always useful).

Comment: I had a similar problem before, which i went around by reading the port with a C executable through subprocesses in python. I have a theory, which invloves `cbytes` I sadly don't have a serial cable to check...

Comment: Thank you for the response. This means there is no way of directly using Pyserial for this. Because decoding of this stream aint't possible?

Comment: Yes using pyserial is possible for what you want. How you unpack the 8 bytes you are reading needs to be done differently. I suspect you want to use https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html instead of `str(bytestream)`. Maybe something like `msg_id, msg_content = struct.unpack('>Ii', bytestream)`